# Perform tasks when the user has responded to a recation, otherwise do nothing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I want that when the user writes a message, my bot should send a message. And once the user has responded to that message, the user should send further instructions.

I have the problem that when the user sends a message, the bot sends the message with the reactions, but as soon as the user sends a second message. The bot sends a message again.

The bot should therefore only send another message once the user has reacted. How can this be done?

I tried this with the `responsed` variable.

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

class command(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
            if message.author == self.bot.user:
                return
     
            else:

                  # check if channel exists
                  if (channel is None):
                      responsed = True
                     if(responsed):
                       responsed = False
                       ...
                       await message.author.send("Hello")
                       # add reactions

                       reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) # check reactions

                       if(reaction.emoji == '✅'):
                           responsed = True
                     else:
                        pass # do nothing
                  else:
                    await message.author.send("How are you?")
                

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(command(bot))
```

1. User sends a Message
   *1.1. check if user reacted*
   1.2 if a message is sent and not reacted then pass
2. Bot replies with Hello -> Wait for reaction
   2.1 bot adds reaction
   2.2 if user sends a second message 2 will started again. That should be forbidden.
3. User Reacts
4. Bot send How are you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you're trying to do, is that discord.py, and the discord API in general, is designed to run a bot on multiple servers, on multiple channels, etc.

This means that, if you want to forbid a user sending a second message, you have to specify what you mean with that. Not twice on the same channel? Not twice for the same user? Should there be some form of a timeout?

I see you're currently working only in private channels (which you can also check with `if isinstance(message.channel, discord.abc.PrivateChannel)` if you want to do that properly) In that case, you might want to restrict it like "not if in the last x messages in the private channel." You can do this with another guard clause at start, here shown with the entire list you're using:

```py
if not isinstance(message.channel, discord.abc.PrivateChannel):
    return

if message.author == self.bot.user:
    return

previous_messages = await message.channel.history(limit=10).flatten()
if any([(message.content == "Hello" and message.author == self.bot.user) for message in previous_messages]):
    return

... # Rest of the function
```

I personally don't think it's the cleanest, but it will at least work. (if I didn't make a typo somewhere...)

If I can give you one do-something-else bit of advice: use buttons and views instead. Those have this type of callback functionality build-in. :-)

I hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much! That helps a lot. How would you do that with buttons? Do you have a link to this, code snippet? That would be great. Thanks.